# ignoring empty lines and perform sdiff

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
sdiff "$t1" "$t2" | grep -c  '[>]'
```

THis command only works if there are no empty lines in the second file. How can I change it so that it ignores the empty lines from both file1 and file2 and perform `sdiff`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww: Is bash not a programming language in your eyes?

Answer (score 2):

Use the -B option to ignore blank lines:

```
sdiff -B "$t1" "$t2" | grep -c '[>]'
```